# Storing scientific content on github

Tags: publications, preprint, science

I have a scientific paper that I would like to protect from theft or other proprietary data, is it possible to store the data and the manuscript in a private github repository as a pre-print in order to prove my ownership just in case? There are supposed to be timestamps and such.

Thanks for the help.

I tried storing it on my personal website however I am not sure if this might be enough.

Comment: Who is going to steal your paper? Who’s proprietary data?

Comment: @JonCuster Regarding the first question I don't think that's relevant, by proprietary data I mean anything that goes with my article.

Comment: The reason it's relevant to know what you're protecting and who you're protecting it from is that the answers will depend on these answers to these questions. Security analysis requires a **threat model**. If this is purely about establishing scientific precedence, then the best thing is probably to post it to ArXiv or another *public* preprint server. If it's not at the preprint stage but you're worried about someone stealing it from your computer, work on storing it more securely. If you're worried about commercially valuable IP, there would be yet another answer ...

Comment: Since you are afraid someone will steal something, yes it is relevant. People don’t ‘steal’ papers…

Comment: I think this is very close to being a duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/158831/pre-print-service-like-arxiv-but-with-private-option-so-i-can-correct-my-mistak . For what purpose do you want to be able to "prove your ownership" of this document later?