# Does vixra hold copyright over any submission to it?

Tags: preprint

I have read the following links

- [vixra.org/practices](https://vixra.org/practices)
- [vixra.org/submit](https://vixra.org/submit)

The only relevant line seems to be

> By submitting your documents to viXra.org, you declare that all authors and other copyright owners of the work have given permission for distribution on the website and that you will inform us of any change of conditions.

Does this mean that they do not hold any copyright over my work?
Sorry if I am being too naive. I want to make sure of everything before landing in a mess.

This question was asked in response to [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/160344/126277)

Comment: Copyright remains with the authors unless explicitly given up. Not just for this site, but in general.

Comment: Note that vixra is not seen as a reputable site for scientific papers. At least in my field, it is viewed as a place for crackpot or crank papers. If you have done a serious piece of research, consider posting it to arXiv instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer seems to be: No.

[See here](https://vixra.org/submit): "viXra.org does not require that authors grant any specific license to viXra.org. Copyright is assumed to remain entirely with the authors of any articles submitted."