# Is it a good idea to put detailed supplementary analyses to a publication on ArXiv or Zenodo?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I am often bothered by the fact that interesting information pertaining a manuscript ends up in the supplemental information because of constraints of space, formatting and narrative. It feels like wasting hard-earned results.

I am about to submit a paper which will be accompanied by supplemental information where I will put a very detailed analysis of some specific bit of the paper. This is too detailed to make it to the main text. Because I think they are nice results nonetheless and I would like to squeeze some juice out of them, I was thinking about putting the supplemental info as either an arXiv or Zenodo submission, which would assign it a DOI and thus make it citeable. It would make this info also more discoverable and accessible by someone who is interested in this part but not in the journal paper itself.

Is this a good idea or should I simply submit my extra data as regular supplemental info instead?

Comment: It is very common practice to create a MEGA version of your paper that contains _all_ relevant material, even material that not necessary for the journal submission, to ArXiv.

Comment: @PsySp Not all journals are compatible with arXiv preprints. As a matter of fact, the ones I'm considering for this paper (which are published by the American Chemical Society) are not. So putting the main text on arXiv would preclude submission to these journals.

Comment: Would you be happy putting the supplemental material on a personal home page?

Comment: @aparente001 I would like the sup. info to have a DOI, that is the motivation to use a repository. My website would not offer this feature.

Comment: @Miguel: Do the journals even disallow postprints, i.e., posting your own version on arXiv after the paper has been accepted? Maybe with an embargo period? You can also check whether this policy of the journal is not overriden by applicable law (e.g., in France, the right for authors to deposit their works in repositories is guaranteed by law, under some conditions).

Comment: @a3nm I feel the discussion is barking up the wrong tree. Just to be clear: most journals (at least the ones I am dealing with) do not own copyright of supplemental material, only of the main text. What I do with the supplemental material is therefore up to me. My question is about getting the most out of my supplemental info, since I would not like for it to be only reachable through some obscure link on the journal's website.

Comment: @Miguel: If you are only asking about the supplementary material, then yes, I would think that it's great to deposit it, on arXiv or elsewhere, e.g., on Zenodo (which can host large data sets). It's just that if you do so, it's more convenient for readers if the main text of the paper is included also, so it's better to do it unless it is really disallowed in terms of copyright.

Comment: @a3nm Ok, I get you now. That sounds reasonable but it might be difficult to reuse the main text in practice.

Comment: Would a hybrid approach be helpful?  It sounds like you want the DOI that comes with an arXiv (for example) upload, AND the easy-to-find aspect of posting on something like a personal home page.  If you put code on e.g. arXiv, the documentation at the top could include a link to your home page, where you would hopefully have a pdf of the published paper.  Please correct me if I've misunderstood anything.

Comment: As far as I know, arXiv uploads do not get assigned DOIs.  See https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62480/why-does-arxiv-org-not-assign-dois which seems to still be the case.

Answer (score 1):

If the journals you want to submit your work are not "ArXiv-compatible" you have few options:

1)Put the excluded material in the *appendix* of the arxiv submission.
2)Make a write-up, put it on your web-page, and cite it in the arxiv paper.
3)Create a technical report (with a time stamp) and cite it in your article.

I think the time-stamp feature is critical here.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I expect that the Journal would host supplementing information. If the amoutn and content is significant (e.g. complicated new method), then publishing an extra article should be possible in another journal and referencing that. And nobody keeps you from putting the preprint online as you would do usually.