# Which preprint repositories assign DOIs for free?

Tags: preprint, doi

[ArXiv.org does not assign DOIs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/62480/9425) to its preprints, but [ResearchGate does](https://explore.researchgate.net/display/support/ResearchGate+DOIs). Are there other preprint repositories that assign DOIs for free?

Comment: @TheGuy Yes, I've assigned them to my own preprints. See: [ResearchGate DOIs](https://explore.researchgate.net/display/support/ResearchGate+DOIs). Try adding a preprint [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publications/create?publicationType=preprint); it should let you assign a DOI.

Comment: Why do you want a DOI on sth. that is not 100% final? They are unique and permanent, so you're supposed to keep the target available in perpetuity.

Comment: @Karl [According to ResearchGate](https://explore.researchgate.net/display/support/ResearchGate+DOIs), "DOIs help you: • Make your research citable. • Put a date on your discovery." Also, RG's "DOIs can be generated for most of your unpublished work."

Comment: So is this question an ad for research gate or...?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I was thinking of asking: "Which preprint repositories assign DOIs for free?", but then I thought it might be closed for being a request for "lists".

Comment: I suggest editing the question to essentially "where to obtain a DOI for a preprint for free?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although meant for data, the [Zenodo repository assigns free DOIs](https://blog.zenodo.org/2017/05/30/doi-versioning-launched/). Nothing hinders one from uploading PDFs there.

Answer (score 6):

[Biorxiv](https://www.biorxiv.org) (the main life sciences preprint server) gives DOIs.

Comment: ChemRxiv does that too

Answer (score 4):

[arXiv](https://arxiv.org/) assigns doi automatically since January 2022. And, all earlier articles have been assigned dois.

[New arXiv articles are now automatically assigned DOIs](https://blog.arxiv.org/2022/02/17/new-arxiv-articles-are-now-automatically-assigned-dois/)

Answer (score 1):

No preprint server should be charging authors any fees for DOIs? I would also +1 for BioRxiv or the [Open Science Foundation](https://osf.io/preprints/) has 18 different subject-based preprint repositories that might fit yours.

Answer (score 1):

There is a community-curated [list of preprint servers](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17RgfuQcGJHKSsSJwZZn0oiXAnimZu2sZsWp8Z6ZaYYo/edit#gid=0), and it takes note of which identifier is assigned to content - you can filter those by DOI.

Answer (score 1):

[Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/) is a repository that assigns DOIs for free. You can access it via your GitHub account or ORCID ID.