# Digital object identification in arxiv

Tags: publications, arxiv

A few months ago I have published my paper in arxiv. Now I came to know that a automatic DOI (digital object identification) number is given to it. Is it ok or normal?

I have no idea about DOI. What is the given DOI?

Comment: Ask Google. Google knows all, tells all.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62480/why-does-arxiv-org-not-assign-dois

Answer (score 4):

Since the question of what a DOI is has been answered already by [@Buffy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/75368/buffy), I will only answer the question of whether this is normal or okay.

Since January 2022 arXiv is automatically assigning a DOI to every preprint in addition to the arXiv identifier. This change hase been [announced on the arxiv.org blog](https://blog.arxiv.org/2022/02/17/new-arxiv-articles-are-now-automatically-assigned-dois/).

One of the reasons for this change is the goal to make the preprints easier to discover via different search engines.

**Update May 2022**: Now all existing arXiv preprints have a DOI (thank you [@Jake](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/156103/jake) for this information).

Comment: update: All arXiv-ids now contain a DOI link.

Comment: @Jake this is what is meant by "Since January 2022 arXiv is automatically assigning a DOI to *every* preprint". Do you think that something should be added here?

Comment: this means that we backfilled DOIs for all 2+ million entries in our repository. It was the plan to do this once the first new papers and recent years were completed, and they now have been.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks! Sorry, I did not get the original comment. I will add this information to the answer.

Comment: No worries. We only completed this part of the project about a month ago, so your original answer is still valid... all of arXiv now have DOI in addition to our persistent arXiv-ids.

Answer (score 0):

A google search will turn up the link to the official site: https://www.doi.org.

It will also give a link to the neutral explanations at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier.

From Wikipedia:

> A digital object identifier (DOI) is a persistent identifier or handle used to identify objects uniquely, standardized by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO).

See the links for more.

ArXiv has information about automatic assignment of a DOI here: https://arxiv.org/help/bib_feed