# Publishing as an independent researcher

Tags: paper-submission, independent-researcher, publishers

Could I submit a (Math) paper in a journal (i.e. [ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/) or [Annals of mathematics](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/)) as an independent researcher (not associated with any university)?

What is the process to submit a paper without affiliation?

Comment: You might look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12894/submitting-to-arxiv-when-unaffiliated

Comment: The process to submit a paper as an independent researcher is the same as the process to submit a paper when you are not an independent researcher. Follow the journal's instructions to authors, which are on the journal's website.

Comment: arXiv is not a journal. Re: arXiv, see [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/1506/11365).

Comment: In general, you may find all the other questions tagged [independent-researcher + publications](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-researcher+publications) helpful.