# Independent research

Tags: publications, research-process, independent-researcher, publishability, publication-bias

I'm considering taking up freelance journalism full-time, while also hoping to publish research on cultural studies in established journals. I have been published on a research website before, and have also presented papers, but this was all about 5 years ago.

Wanted to know what the hurdles are while publishing academic papers as an independent researcher?

PS: I have done two postgraduate degrees in the field and I'm trying to build up a research portfolio before I apply to PhD programmes.

Comment: Does any of your research require ethics oversight (usually because it involves collecting data on human subjects or experiments on animals)?

Comment: also related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83309/publishing-as-an-independent-researcher

Answer (score 2):

A PhD program is ultimately intended to *train you to perform and publish research* in your field of interest.

Most PhD students find this process very difficult, especially in the beginning, even with help. Most people *with* successfully completed PhD training *still* find this process very difficult, especially as they take their first steps independently of their mentor (though that doesn't mean mentorship ends at the end of a PhD; post-doctoral positions ordinarily have an explicit mentorship component, and tenure-track faculty still rely on mentors for advice).

The most immediate barriers you will encounter are not issues of "independent research" but rather issues of *not having research training*. If you've completed two postgraduate degrees, it sounds like you're ready for the full-time research training that comes with a PhD degree, and you should start applying now.